# Google Apps Scripts limit: Can I share a file to partner's account to use their limit?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-apps

I have a quite big google spreadsheet file with a lot of Apps Script functions that get data from an API every minute. That's why it causes exceeding limits of google (service used too much computer time, urlfetch called too many times, and etc.).

Now I have 2 questions:

1. Can I share my sheet to my partner's account and he will run it with his own limit? Does Google continue to count the limit from me or not? (Ex: The function execution time limit is 90 min/day/account. So if I used all of that, I will share that file to my partner's account and he will continue to run it for me with his own 90 mins limit. Is it possible? )
2. If 1. is impossible, maybe I will need to make a copy of my sheet from account A to other account (B). Then I will run the sheet on A from 0 am to 12am. And from 12am to 12pm I run the file on B. Can anyone tell me how to disable all script function calls, triggers of a google account? (So that I will disable B when A runs and disbale A when B runs)?
   Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1: The Google app script quota limit is linked with the Google account of the person who is running the script and not the owner of the script or the spreadsheet. So when your friend runs the script, then the quota limit is calculated against his/ her account.

2: It is not possible to disable the trigger but you can delete the trigger using  `deleteTrigger()` and you can re create a new one by using `ScriptApp.newTrigger(functionName)`.